# How do I create a keyValue pair (display field) by combining/having two fields in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-3.0, key-value, dropdown

I need help getting two values (for human friendly dropdown) in a key-value pair using ***find*** or ***get*** or anything else. I need help with the simplest method of doing this in CakePHP.

Here's my attempt:

1. in my controller

   ```
     $users = $this->LocationsUser->Users->find('list', [
       'limit' => 1,
       'keyField' => 'id',
       'valueField' => ['first_name', 'last_name']
     ])->where(['id' => $id]);
   ```
2. In my view

   ```
     echo $this->Form->input('user_id', [
           'options' => $users,
           'type' => 'select',
           'multiple' => false,
         ]);
   ```
3. The result on my drop-down:

   ```
   <option value="10">Fabian;Pankiers</option>
   ```

See I need a result without the semicolon **";"**. Now I can use javascript to remove the semicolon but then thats overkill. Is there a simple way to achieve this within CakePHP 3?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this, here's three of them:

### Use a callback for the `valueField`

Use a callback and stitch the value together by using values from the results.

```
$query = $this->LocationsUser->Users
    ->find('list', [
        'valueField' => function ($row) {
            return $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
        }
    ])
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Finding Key/Value Pairs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)**

### Result formatters

Use a result formatter that stitches the values together, that's what the `list` finder does internally too, and basically the same as the above example, just more complicated.

```
$query = $this->LocationsUser->Users
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
    ->formatResults(function($results) {
        /* @var $results \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface */
        return $results->combine(
            'id',
            function($row) {
                return $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'];
            }
        );
    })
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
```

#### Combined with virtual properties

You could also use (re-)use virtual properties here, given for example a property name `full_name` defined in your `User` entity class:

```
protected function _getFullName()
{
    return $this->_properties['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->_properties['last_name'];
}
```

You could just return that in the formatter instead of manually combining the two fields again:

```
function($row) {
    return $row['full_name'];
}
```

The same could be done in the `valueField` example.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Creating Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)**

### Computed fields

Add a computed field and use that one for the `valueField` option

```
$query = $this->LocationsUser->Users
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'concatenated'
    ]);
$query
    ->select([
        'id',
        'concatenated' => $query->func()->concat([
            'first_name' => 'literal',
            ' ',
            'last_name' => 'literal'
        ])
    ])
    ->where(['id' => $id]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

### Override the list finder

If you want your custom list to be always applied, you could override the `list` finder in your `Users` table class.

```
use Cake\ORM\Query;

// ...

public function findList(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->find()
        ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
        // etc ...
        ;
}
```

That way you can continue to use `find('list')`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**

Comment: Thanks @ndm, you're awesome! I've used the Computed fields method (with concatenated) and works perfectly!

Comment: Great solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Simple and quick solution, worked like a charm (**CakePHP 3.2.6**):

```
$users = $this->LocationsUser->Users->find('list', [
    'limit' => 1,
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => function ($e) {
            return $e->get('first_name'). ' ' . $e->get('last_name');
        }
])->where(['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Added that to my answer too, not sure why I've overlooked it initially.