# Using valuefield in cakephp 3.1 with relation

Tags: cakephp-3.0

The sections are related to the level and degree. So I need  to show on the field select level, grade and section.
Reading the cakephp 3 book found that using "valueField" I can show the field I want. But this time I need to show two fields.

In my controller:

```
$secciones =  $this->Users->Secciones->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id',
    'valueField' => ['nivele.nivel']



])->contain(['Niveles', 'Grados']);
```

When I put in the valueField ['nivele.nivel','grado.grado'] only show a semicolon.

How can display two relationship in the select field?

Thanks.

> I readed the solution in
>   [How do I create a keyValue pair by combining/having two fields in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-by-combining-having-two-fields-in-cakephp-3)
>   but in that case no relation. In my case i need to use two fields with
>   relation.
>
> Reading the solution in
>   [How do I create a keyValue pair by combining/having two fields in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-by-combining-having-two-fields-in-cakephp-3)
>   I did this:

```
     $secciones = $this->User->Secciones
->find()
->select(['id', 'nivele_id', 'grado_id'])
->formatResults(function($results) {
    /* @var $results \Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface */
    return $results->combine(
        'id',
        function($row) {
            return $row['nivele.nivel'] . ' ' . $row['grado.grado'];
        }
    );
})
->contain(['Niveles', 'Grados']);
```

But I have a fatal error :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a keyValue pair by combining/having two fields in CakePHP 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-by-combining-having-two-fields-in-cakephp-3)

Comment: "_... but in that case no relation ..._" Unless there is more to this than what you are actually describing in your question, it is _exactly_ the same problem, and whatever your associations look like, the former mentioned solution is definitely applicable.

Comment: It is not the same problem. I do not know how to place the relationship in the query

Comment: "_... how to place the relationship in the query_" I have no clue what exactly that means, and you haven't mentioned anything like that initially. Please add some proper explanation to your question.

Comment: Sorry my english. I updated the question.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is not how you access nested properties/array keys, which should be more like `$row['nivele']['nivel']`... this should not cause a fatal error. When you receive an error, then please post the complete, exact error message (and for non-fatal errors also the stracktrace). ps, depending on the type of association (I can only assume that these are `belongsTo` ones), you may need to add the fields that you want to combine to the `select()` list, ie `Niveles.nivel` and `Grados.grado`.