# two join fields as valueField

Tags: php, cakephp, join, field

I am trying to combine two join fields as a valueField in a dropdown combo.
After checking [https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-display-field-by-combining-having-two-fields-i) and [How do I create a keyValue pair (display field) by combining/having two fields in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999490/how-do-i-create-a-keyvalue-pair-display-field-by-combining-having-two-fields-i) I tried the following:

**This works:**

```
$authorities = $this->Books->Authorities->find('list', [
            'valueField' => 'author.name'])
            ->contain(['Authors', 'AuthorTypes']);
```

**This works too:**

```
$authorities = $this->Books->Authorities->find('list', [
            'valueField' => 'author_type.name'])
            ->contain(['Authors', 'AuthorTypes']);
```

**But this doesn't:**

```
$authorities = $this->Books->Authorities->find('list', [
            'valueField' => function ($row) {
                return $row['author.name'] . ' - ' . $row['author_type.name'];
            }])
        ->contain(['Authors', 'AuthorTypes']);
```

**I can't understand why. Any ideas? :)**

Comment: following the example [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#customize-key-value-output) should be `$row->author->name`

Comment: I must be blind...because not even now can I see it is the same example ^_ ^!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments suggested, follow this [examples](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#customize-key-value-output).

Your code should be:

```
$authorities = $this->Books->Authorities->find('list', [
            'valueField' => function ($row) {
                return $row->author->name . ' - ' . $row->author->name;
            }])
            ->contain(['Authors', 'AuthorTypes']);
```

This is called `Customize Key-Value Output`. The $row argument is an object instead of a simple array_object.